# Avoid showing an element while the promise is being fufilled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface

I have a promise which takes a bit of time [as mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60447506/2404470) to fulfill as it resolves the values from an API.

We wanted to show/hide the feature only in certain cases. In general cases, we wanted the feature to be visible only.

The problem is that till the time the promise is fulfilled - the field is visible. The promise takes 1-1.5 seconds to fulfill depending on the network speed. After 1-1.5 seconds the element is hidden. This gives a weird experience to the end-user.

This is the timeline of this crazy user experience:

1. Time A - Element visible
2. Sum of Time A and 1-1.5 seconds - Element is hidden

I'm trying to understand if there is a better way to handle this situation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you are using to achieve this? If you are using a state variable to hide/show the element it shouldn't be be visible until you set it to true.

Comment: Usually the user interface solution for an element that you won't know if it should be visible for some amount of time is to initially start out with the element as hidden and only make it visible when your response comes back and you now know that it should be visible.  This keeps things that should be hidden from every showing to the user.  Said differently, the default condition is that they are hidden and they are only made visible when you know they should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional for this.  The following example shows how certain elements are only shown after API data arrives.

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  
  const setLoadingState = () => {
    setData();
    setIsLoading(true);
  }
  
  const getApiData = () => {
    setLoadingState();
    setTimeout(() => { // <-- Add some additional 'delay' for the sake of this demo
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => setData(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)))
        .catch(err => setData(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)))
        .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));    
    }, 1300);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={getApiData}>Load API Data</button>
      {data && // <-- Conditional statement, like saying `if (data) { ... }`
        <div>
          <h4 style={{color: 'blue'}}>I am some fancy html that is hidden before my API data arrives</h4>
          <pre>{data}</pre>
        </div>}
      {isLoading && // <-- Another conditional..
        <h3>Loading...</h3>}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```